# Connection between complementarity problem and optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, definition, convex-optimization, duality-theorems, operations-research

I do not understand the connection between complementarity problems and optimization problems. I have tried to look at other definitions for complementarity problem to see if that would help me with the connection but it did not.

My question is:

**What excatly is a complementarity problem?** 
- This is where my main problem is because I do not understand the definition of a complementarity problem. Is it possible to show/explain the definition graphically? Maybe using cones and dual cones?

**Why (and when) are complementarity problems useful for optimization problems?**

Best Husky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementarity problems is simply optimization problems with a special kind of constraints. Essentially orthogonality constraints between two non-negative vectors, $x\geq 0, y\geq 0, x^Ty = 0$.

This arise, for example, in purely geometric applications (orthogonality constraints), or in situations where you want to encode either-or conditions ($x_i$ is zero or $y_i$ is zero, such as when you want to encode optimality conditions where either the dual variable is zero, or the slack is zero, or both)

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you very much :) What about complementarity problems and equilibrium problems? 

Is the connection between these two that we can solve equilibrium problems by formulating them as complementarity problem? Lets for examples assume that we have two players where each player maximizes profit s.t. some constraints are satisfied and we wish to find the nash-cournot equlibrium. 

We can solve this by writting up the complementarity problem.. but why is it that we cannot just solve each of the two maximization problems with the equilibrium constraint?

Comment: Is it because we then don't look at it as a whole? but by writing up the complementarity problem we take into consideration the maximization of profit for each player but also the nash equilibrium for both.