# Does the set of pairs of orthogonal vectors have a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, reference-request, terminology, orthogonality

For $n\in\{1,2,\ldots\}$, define

$$S := \big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\times\mathbb{R}^n \;\;\big|\;\; x \perp y\big\}.$$

So if $n=1$, then $S$ is the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes in the Euclidean plane, which can be viewed asymptotes of parabolas.

More generally, we get the union of all pairs of orthogonal subspaces.

**Does the set $S$ have a name? Are there any interesting properties known about $S$?**

Why care? Sets of this type show up in the discussion of complementarity problems, e.g., here: [Connection between complementarity problem and optimization problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819715/connection-between-complementarity-problem-and-optimization-problem)

Any reference would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If we add the additional constraint that $x$ and $y$ are unit vectors, then $S$ can be thought of as the set of isometric embeddings of $\Bbb R^2$ into $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Maybe another way to look at this is to consider vectors $ x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{2n})$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and the quadratic form $q(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i x_{n+i}$. Then the set in question should be the $0$-level set of this form?